# Is there a better way to unpack lists of tuples in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have a list consisting of many 5 object long tuples. There are several places in my code were I unpack each element in the list, like so:

```
for a, b, c, d, e in tuple_list: 
    print(f"{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}")
```

My question is, is there a better way to refer to a, b, c, d, and e instead of having to manually write each name every time I iterate through the array?

I'm looking for some solution where I could say

```
UNPACKED_VALUES = [a, b, c, d, e]
for UNPACKED_VALUES in tuple_list:
    print(f"{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}")
```

Does anyone know if anything like this exists in Python?

Comment: Not an answer but do you control the format of `tuple_list`? If yes, maybe convert it to contain classes, diets, or some other more descriptive item.

Comment: To my knowledge, something like ypur second snippet of code is impossible (at lesst without some trickery). More over, I'm not sure you'd want to. This code never explicitly assigns to a,b,c,d, or e within the loop which will make it much harder  to read for anyone else.

Comment: Note that in this particular case you could write `for tuple_el in tuple_list: print(tuple_el)` and get almost the same output.

Comment: Yeah maybe my best bet is to refactor to use a class.